# The Alt+F12 shortcut stopped working for me in Far Manager. How can I figure out what happened?

Tags: far-manager

Around Summer 2022 the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> local shortcut in Far Manager (Folders History) suddenly stopped working for me.

I was looking for software which possibly shadows it with a global shortcut key, because the option was otherwise working by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or via the main menu, but it's too cumbersome to invoke like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use HotKeyList by NirSoft but it only shows if the global key combination shortcut is bound. The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> was in the list.

I've started to iterate by looking at the most possible culprit in Task Manager, killing programs one by one and refreshing the list of global shortcuts with <kbd>F5</kbd> in HotKeyList.

The search iterations narrowed down to Razer Cortex which accompanied my Razer keyboard and mouse. Indeed it was a "Exit Game Desktop" shortcut, which can be switched off by clicking a cog next to the minimize button in upper-right, going to "Hotkeys" section on the left and clearing the corresponding field.

After that the Far Manager <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut started to work again.